# Upload iOS app to AppStore (An error occurred uploading to the App Store.)

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I can't upload new version of app to appstore after full OS update. Try install java version 9+ and 8+, doesn't work. In Application Loader I get this log:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.apple.transporter.launcher.Application.start(Application.java:206)
    at com.apple.transporter.launcher.Application.main(Application.java:519)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: could not find needed OSGiFramework
    at com.apple.transporter.osgi.BootstrapHelper.setupClassLoader(BootstrapHelper.java:120)
    at com.apple.transporter.osgi.FelixOSGiBootstrapper.bootstrap(FelixOSGiBootstrapper.java:9)
```

XCode 9.2, java version "1.8.0_151"

Comment: Same here, at monday it working fine but not today.

Comment: What OS did you upgrade to? 10.13.2 High Sierra? Or something else?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Same error here. XCode(9.2) and java(9.0.1).

This command line solve my problem :

```
rm -R ~/.itmstransporter
```

Regards

Comment: Workd for me. Also due to xCode 9 there were 2 icons missing in assets file. addition of those 2 icons and above command together worked for me.

Comment: Also solve my issue on Xcode 10.2, thanks! (I failed to upload the app with Fastlane after updated the gems.)

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same issue on Windows. No changes to java or my itms install and it suddenly stopped working. I reinstalled itms and deleted ~/.itmstransporter, but no luck. After not using my computer for the weekend, my terminal was still open so I tried again -- but this time it worked.

My assumption is that itms does something to talk to the internet and that was down and for some reason that manifested as "java.lang.IllegalStateException: could not find needed OSGiFramework".